# Get date like value after substring

Tags: postgresql

I am working with a call logs column where call centre agents log events such as when a customer has promised to make a payment and when they want to be called later.

Sample cal log looks like this.

```
note#..customer is making payment today #ESCA#NotEscalated #DSRID#999999 #out#outboundcallRO #out#ANSWER BY CUSTOMER talked #c#nosurvey #m#MOBILE tgsx.._ 1 #g#Sales/Credit call followup #s#MAXI #c#REQUEST #pref#NonGiven #SC#NonGiven #pref#nofault #PTdrp# #d#non #PTcollect# #d#non #Reason for not paying_ #D#Other financial priorities #Promise to pay on_ #d#01-JUN #Call later on_ #d#02-JUN
```

I would like to select the date part after the substrings
**#Promise to pay on_ #d#** and **#Call later on_ #d#**

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: And consider to normalize the schema a store the different parts of the information in different columns from the beginning.

Comment: @stickybit that's a good suggestion. I will consider it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use Postgres' `SUBSTRING` function, which supports regular expressions with capture groups:

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(col, '#Promise to pay on_ #d#(.*?)(?:\s|#|$)') AS pay_on_date,
    SUBSTRING(col, '#Call later on_ #d#(.*?)(?:\s|#|$)') AS call_on_date
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

As an alternative to the above, we can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^.*#Promise to pay on_ #d#(.*?)(\s|#|$).*$', '$1') AS pay_on_date,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^.*#Call later on_ #d#(.*?)(\s|#|$).*$', '$1') AS call_on_date
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: forgot to mention I am working with redshift and it throws the following error when I try your implementation 
** Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;**

Comment: @TitoLulu Try using `REGEXP_REPLACE`, q.v. my updated answer above.

Comment: **error:  Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'n_ #d#(.*?>>>HERE>>>)(?:s|#|$)'.** when I use the REGEXP_REPLACE

Comment: I removed the non capturing markers.  Try it again.

Comment: [It is working in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6751151d0a6ca7e67295b5b029aca658), you must have some other problem not related to my answer.

Comment: Probably an AWS redshift issue, I am investigating. Thanks